# Domain of $e^{1/(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: calculus

I have this function, I want do determine the domain of it: $e^{1/(x^2+y^2)}$.

Is the answer: $y \neq \sqrt{x}$?

That's what I've already tried to do:

D = $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$

$y^2 \neq -x^2$

$y \neq \sqrt{x}^2$

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this function on complex numbers as well as reals?

Comment: The only point for which $x^2+y^2=0$ is the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: $x^2$ and $y^2$ are always $\geq 0$.  So you see that the only way the denominator can be zero is for *both* $x$ and $y$ to be zero.  This tells you that the domain is everything except $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y^2 \ne -x^2$ is correct but it does not follow that $y \ne \sqrt{x^2}.$ Not sure where you got that from. Note that if $y = \sqrt{x^2}$ we have $y^2 = x^2,$ not $y^2 = -x^2.$

I'll assume you're only considering real-valued $x$ and $y$ and not complex. Note $x^2\ge 0$ and $-y^2\le0$ so the only possible way for them to be equal is when they're both equal to zero. Which means $x=y=0.$